# Length of a vector if evoked from ls

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R, so I am sorry if the question was asked here before, however I did not found something similar:

What I needed is just to return the *length* of a vector (I have two vectors of the length 5 and 6 in the environment) from a command, conjoint with *ls*:

```
 for (i in ls()) {print (length(noquote(i)))}
```

However, for both vectors this returns 1.

Thanks for a prompt.

Comment: `for( i in ls() ) {print( length( get(i) ) )}`

Comment: In this situation you want `print(length(get(i)))`. But rarely do you want to print everything in `ls()`.

Comment: Could you please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? `dput` output of your vectors would be helpful.

Comment: `ls()` calls the names of all vectors / dataframes / etc. in your environment.  Each name is only going to have a length of 1.  So it did what you told it to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls()` returns a vector of strings (of type `character`). You are looping through those strings, removing the quotes from them, and then asking how long these `character` objects are.

What you want to do is access the `object` with a given name. To do that, you pass the name of the object as a `character` to the function `get`. `get` will accept the name of an object, search for it in the environment, and return the **actual object**, if it exists. You can then pass that into `length` to get the length of the object:

```
for (i in ls()) {print (length(get(i)))}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` with `mget` to count the length of each object in your global environment. `mget` takes a character vector with the names of objects (in this case a vector of object names in your global environment returned by `ls()`), and returns a list of objects stored in each name. `sapply` then counts the `length` of each element of the list and return a vector of lengths:

```
sapply(mget(ls()), length)
```

Comment: this is similar to `lengths(mget(ls()))`